# Connect a router to pc to share pc's wireless (kind of repeater)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a wireless internet connection on my laptop I want to share with others. I tried the hotspot, but that didt work. So I thought I could connect a wireless router (DLINK) to my pc lan port and share my wireless with my lan. Then others could connect to the DLINK and use internet from the laptop.

I have tested to disable DHCP on the DLINK and connected it to a working router, then I get internet. But if I connect the router to my lan port, I get no internet. I have tried to enable DHCP on DLINK, but that dosent work either.

So any tip..?

Ps
I have windows 8 on laptop

Comment: Why didn't the hotspot work? I presume it's because you've only got one adaptor, but that raises the question of why the rest of the devices can't connect to the original wireless network? Anyway, what you're looking to do is internet connection sharing and plenty of guides online to do it.

Comment: Do I have to have two nic's for hotspot? I have used the dos cmd to create a hotspot. Everything on compter looks ok, but if I connect a device I dont get internet. I do however get a IP. So im not sure why its not working, I am going to use this system another place (with very bad signal) then my house, where I have a working router. The other place I dont have access to the router.

Comment: Yes, you'll generally need two nics. One is connected to the internet, the other is 'running' the hotspot. You get an IP because the hotspot is working - but there's no internet connection from it.

Comment: So did I thought, But how do I define what nic to use for hotspot and what to use with internet wifi? I use the cmd
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=test key=12345678
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
and then get a new network connection
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lfnzV6R_emYBqXXSN2c5XCs2YKuberXP/view)